# Extracting a node where xmlns is set to blank

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g, xml-namespaces

I'm having difficulties extracting the value from certain nodes in an XML structure using `XMLTABLE`. Below query works perfectly when you remove the `xmlns=""` attribute from the `SubListItem` nodes. And as you can see, the XML already has a default namespace. I honestly have no clue how I can deal with this "blanking out" of the namespace on certain nodes like this. 
For further clarification, the creation of this XML is not within my control and is provided by a third-party. I've also changed the names of the nodes and the content from the delivered files while preserving the structure of the XML.

```
SELECT f.airline, f.flightnumber, fl.gate
  FROM xmltable(
        xmlnamespaces(
                 default 'http://some/name.space',
                 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd",
                 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi"
                 ),
       'Body/Flight'
        passing xmltype(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://some/name.space">
  <Sender>
    <System>ConnectionManagement</System>
  </Sender>
  <Flight>
    <Airline>ABC</Airline>
    <Number>1234</Number>
    <SubList>
      <SubListItem xmlns="">
        <Gate>X</Gate>
      </SubListItem>
      <SubListItem xmlns="">
        <Gate>Y</Gate>
      </SubListItem>
      <SubListItem xmlns="">
        <Gate>Z</Gate>
      </SubListItem>
    </SubList>
  </Flight>
</Body>'
      )
      columns airline varchar2(100) path 'Airline'
     , flightNumber VARCHAR2(5) path 'Number'
     , subList XMLTYPE path 'SubList'
  ) f
, xmltable (
    xmlnamespaces( default 'http://some/name.space'),
    '/SubList/SubListItem'
    passing f.subList
    columns gate varchar2(5) path 'Gate'
  ) fl
;
```

How can I target the `Gate` node when the XML looks like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the default namespace alone in the second XMLTable, and specify a named namespace for the path you do have:

```
...
, xmltable (
    xmlnamespaces( 'http://some/name.space' as "ns"),
    '/ns:SubList/SubListItem'
    passing f.subList
    columns gate varchar2(5) path 'Gate'
  ) fl
;

AIRLINE    FLIGH GATE
---------- ----- -----
ABC        1234  X    
ABC        1234  Y    
ABC        1234  Z
```

The SubList still has to match that, but as the child nodes don't the default is incorrect the way you have it. If you remove the `xmlns=""` as you mentioned in the question then that inherits the namespace from its parent, so your default works. With that override to no-namespace you can't use a default.

Comment: Oh wow, never occured to me to go about it in this way. The SubList inherited the default namespace, and because of that I figured I had to go about it in the same way with the extraction. I also didn't try to use that same namespace as a namespace selector. Brilliant, it works!